# Windows Login from C++ service

Tags: c++, windows, service, authentication

I am trying to create a Windows Service that is able to log on my user programatically into my local windows 10 pc the same as if i was typing directly in front of my keyboard. (I want to be able to initialize my session remotely)
I am using LogonUser and it returns properly but i will never see the user to appear as loged in in the Task Manager for example.

This is what i have tried now:

```
  BSINFO(L"Login User...");
  HANDLE sessToken = nullptr;
  BOOL bRes = LogonUserW(
    L"TestUser",
    L".",
    L"1234",
    LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE,
    LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT,
    &sessToken);
  if (bRes)
  {
    PROFILEINFO profInfo;
    ZeroMemory(&profInfo,sizeof(PROFILEINFO));
    profInfo.dwSize = sizeof(PROFILEINFO);
    profInfo.lpUserName = L"TestUser";
    profInfo.lpServerName = L"";
    bRes = LoadUserProfileW(sessToken,&profInfo);
    if (!bRes)
    {
      DWORD dwError = GetLastError();
      BSERROR(L"Error LoadUserProfileW. %d '%ls'", dwError, GetLastErrorW(dwError).c_str());
    }
  }
  else
  {
    DWORD dwError = GetLastError();
    BSERROR(L"Error login user. %d '%ls'", dwError, GetLastErrorW(dwError).c_str());
  }
```

Is it something possible to do?

Comment: Are you trying to re-implement Remote Desktop Protocol (i.e. Terminal Services) from scratch? There is much more involved with working with Windows terminal sessions. What you have so far is a token with a logon session, which I presume is associated with terminal session 0, the non-interactive services session. A trusted system service can assign such a token to another session, if for example it needs to start a process in a user's interactive session, but that's no where near the same as starting a new session.

Comment: More or less i want to develop my own remoted desktop, i want to log remotelly into my computer and i will then stream my desktop, everything is working but i don´t know just how to do an interactive login into my PC remotelly:(

Comment: `LogonUser` creates a logon session. This has nothing to do with creating an interactive console or terminal session, other than the fact that the token it returns is what binds the logon session to the terminal session.

Comment: And is there any way of creating that console or interative desktop?